# Controlling the functions of foreign site

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I have hosted a simple webpage on my laptop. This page, sends request to another page [global www.* domain]; Page X which in-turn invokes another webpage; Page-Y and the final result shown on the screen is Page-Y.

Now, since the coding/source of the Page-Y is hosted on another site, I don't have any control over it.

Is there any method that I can invoke the functions and prevent some functions of page Y?

Comment: No. You cannot do this, period, UNLESS page Y has provided some means of giving that control.

Comment: Is reverse proxying an option? Alternatively, you're stuck with function emulation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot affect the server-side code with an HTTP request. If you were able to access the other site, you could set a URL parameter such as `www.example.com/page-y.php?f=1`, but it would still be controlled by the remote site.

Comment: Yes, I can set a URL parameter for Page-X, but that will not affect page-Y that is ultimately being displayed.

Comment: If you have NO control over page Y, you can't control what runs server-side on page Y.